# Where in this sample code is the backtracking happening?

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, maze

```
package maze;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Maze {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int board[][] = new int[31][121];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                board[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
        int r = rand.nextInt(board.length);
        while(r%2==0){
            r=rand.nextInt(board.length);
        }

        int c = rand.nextInt(board[0].length);
        while(c%2==0){
            c=rand.nextInt(21);
        }
        System.out.format("r is %d and c is %d\n",r,c);
        board[r][c]=0;
        recursion(r,c,board);
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j]==1) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else if (board[i][j]==0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
    public static void recursion(int r, int c,int[][] board){
        ArrayList<Integer> randDirections = generateDirections();
        int[] randDir=new int[randDirections.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < randDir.length; i++) {
            randDir[i]=randDirections.get(i);
            System.out.println(randDir[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < randDir.length; i++) {

            switch(randDir[i]){
                case 1:
                    //checks up position
                    if (r-2>=0) {
                        if (board[r-2][c]!=0) {
                            board[r-2][c] = 0;
                            board[r-1][c] = 0;
                            recursion(r - 2, c,board);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //checks right position
                    if (c + 2 <= board[0].length - 1){
                        if (board[r][c + 2] != 0) {
                            board[r][c + 2] = 0;
                            board[r][c + 1] = 0;
                            recursion(r, c + 2,board);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //checks down position
                    if (r + 2 <= board.length - 1){
                        if (board[r + 2][c] != 0) {
                            board[r+2][c] = 0;
                            board[r+1][c] = 0;
                            recursion(r + 2, c,board);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //checks left position
                    if (c - 2 >= 0){
                        if (board[r][c - 2] != 0) {
                            board[r][c - 2] = 0;
                            board[r][c - 1] = 0;
                            recursion(r, c - 2,board);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }  
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> generateDirections(){
        ArrayList<Integer> randoms = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            randoms.add(i+1);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(randoms);
        return randoms;
    }
}
```

I can see that my program is backtracking when it cannot make another path for my maze and that my recursion method only stops when it has backtracked all the way back to the first path square. However, I don't know exactly what is doing this. It seems to me that the method should just stop when the for loop of the four random directions is exhausted. Could someone explain to me which part of code is causing it to backtrack and how it works?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elMXlO28Q1U

Comment: Thank you for showing me that video. However, I still don't understand how the part he showed with his stacks and conditions exists in my program. Could you show me how my program is doing the same thing?

Comment: Would you still like an answer?

Comment: Yes anything you could help explain about where backtracking occurs would be great. I think I am misunderstanding something about the way recursion works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the call stack and understanding what is happening at each level of the stack.  "Backtracking" is occurring when one recursive call exhausts its for-loop, after which time, the method returns, popping one level off the stack, and the continuing in the for-loop of the context of the stack level that made the call.

Mapping out just 2 levels of calls can help clarify.  You'll find in the first "level" (the root call of the recursion), the for loop simply iterates as you would expect, *but* it will be interspersed with the processing of the recursive calls it makes (each creating a "next level" of recursion).

The for loop of the bottom layer of the calling stack goes through all of its iterations while the for loop of the layer above may be on only the first iteration.

Comment: You say that the method returns but I don't understand as I only call the method once and I don't have a return statement. Also I don't have any idea which part is supposed to be popping one level off the stack. I watched a video where the stacks were shown more clearly and I understand how the method is supposed to work but I don't know where my method is doing those things. Could you point those spots out for me? Sorry if this is a dumb questions.

Comment: The method calls itself - that's recursion.  Also, every function/method returns when control reaches the end, even if there's no explicit `return` statement.  Sounds like brushing up on the basics of instruction processing and functions might help.

Comment: Here's one of the recursive calls `recursion(r - 2, c,board);`  If you write a method `public void endless() { endless(); }` and call it, you'll quickly get a stack overflow.